# Print first word in each column as a row.

Tags: c

I am trying to design a program that takes our message and keeps a specific number of characters in each row(which is completed). After keeping the characters in that order, I am trying to print the first letter of each column and print it in a line and then move to 2nd column and print those characters in the next line and so on. 
I am able to print the first column using this code but I am not sure how to move to the next column.     Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int row = 0 ;
int i = 0 ;
char message[256] ;

scanf( "%d", &row );
fgets( message, sizeof(message), stdin ) ;

while( message[i] != '\0' )
{
    putchar( message[i] ) ;
    i++ ;
    if( i % row == 0 )
    {
        putchar( '\n' ) ;
    }
    i=i+row-1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: An example message and what output you expect would be helpful.

Comment: If my input is 3
This is a C program.
Thi
S i
S a
 C 
Pro
Gra
m.
Then 1st line is Tss pgm
2nd line should be h acrm

Comment: Why isn't the last half of the message (`Thi S i S a C Pro Gra m`) included in the output?  And I don't think you have the second line right; shouldn't it be `h  Crr.` (each being the character *after* the corresponding one in the first line of output)?

Comment: Scott hunter you are right about the second line and I don't need the last half so I am not printing those lines. I only need it to verify it to choose the first word of each new line.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code that will solve your problem is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
int row = 0 ;
int i = 0 ;
int j=0,length=0;
char message[256] ;
scanf( "%d", &row );
fgets( message, sizeof(message), stdin ) ;
length = strlen(message);//stores the length of the array.
    for(j=1;j<=row;j++) 
    {
        while( i < length )//use this condition in the while loop instead of (message[i]!='\0') in this case.
        {
            putchar(message[i]) ;
            i=i+row;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i=j;
    }       
return 0;
}
```

Note that since you were using a static array and the condition (message[i]!='\0') in the while loop,in most of the cases your code would require accessing an array element beyond the array length which could invoke undefined behaviour.Using a dynamic array or changing the condition in the while loop will prevent such errors.
Moreover,this problem could also be solved if you had stored all the rows in a Two-dimensional array and then displayed each column in a single line.